# NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification not being notified

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, icloud

If an entry is changed in core data on another device, NSLog messages show that it's noticed the changes, but `NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification` is not being called. It takes until a save on my first device for it to know to update my tableview.

This is my code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(iCloudUpdates:)
                                                 name:NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

Anybody know why this might not be working?

Answer (score 3):

First option:
If your problem is a delay in updating both devices, that is normal behavior, Apple doesn't guarantee update timing, but it is usually fast.

If on the other side the problem is that iCloudUpdates method is not called make sure that signature is correct, should be :

```
-(void)iCloudUpdates:(NSNotification*)notification {
  // do your stuff here
}
```

Second option:
 at time of writing, iOS 5 has big big problem with iCloud and CoreData, I recently shipped my application without iCloud support.

If you want to know what is going on turn logging on for both CoreData and iCloud by putting:

```
-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1
-com.apple.coredata.ubiquity.logLevel 3
```

in your scheme manager, under run->arguments tab.

If you see some strange errors in 'destination' device that's the case of iCloud not working for being bugged.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with your code is that in the "addObserver" you've set the object to nil.  The object should be your persistentStoreCoordinator as shown below.

```
__weak NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = self.context.persistentStoreCoordinator;

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(iCloudUpdates:)
                                             name:NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification
                                           object:psc];
```